# ArrayList convert to String

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-studio

I am trying to make a search field in my android application. I need to convert ArrayList to String array in order to display values and search. I have:

```
 inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.plates, R.id.title, mPlatesList);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                Lista.this.myAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
```

and

```
mPlatesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
mPlates = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mPlates.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mPlates.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag
                String targa = c.getString(TAG_TARGA);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_TARGA, targa);
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mPlatesList.add(map);
```

I am getting the above error. I am new at android so I don't know how to convert fromone type to  another.

```
  Error:(32, 38) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(Lista,int,int,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)
        constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
        (argument mismatch; ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> cannot be converted to String[])
        constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable
        (argument mismatch; ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> cannot be converted to List<String>)
```

Comment: if you required ArrayList with HashMap then you have make custom adpter for your list.

Comment: Check out my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954285/edittext-value-not-save-in-listview-dynamically/24956887#24956887

Comment: can you specify which string array you want i mean the ArrayList is  of hashmap. You want the string array of keys or values ?

Comment: well what exactly do you want to display from that data structure?

Comment: @ Preethi Rao I want values. To perform search

Comment: What values? There are MAPS inside your List. All values concatenated? Some values by some condition? Each value individually one by one? You need to specify what you WANT to get in what form.

Comment: I have a list of values (plates) and I am performing a search, so what I want is all values of plates in order to perform search for all of them. Am i clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert an ArrayList to a String[] by calling the toArray method:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String [] table = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

In your example, you don't have any `ArrayList<String>`. This is a list of hashmaps. I don't really get which strings you want to put in the table in the end. Is it the union of all hashmaps value sets ?

EDIT: Ok. Then, you may build a set which is the union of all value set by doing this:

```
Set<String> unionSet = new HashSet<String>();
for(HashMap<String, String> hashMap : mPlatesList){
    unionSet.addAll(hashMap.values());
}
```

Then, you can make an Array out of your Set:

```
String [] table = unionSet.toArray(new String[unionSet.size()]);
```

EDIT2: changed `Map<String, String> hashMap` to `HashMap<String, String> hashMap`
EDIT3: changed toArray call

EDIT4: Here is a whole example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // instantiate mPlatesList
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mPlatesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // fill it with 3 HashMaps
        mPlatesList.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
        mPlatesList.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
        mPlatesList.add(new HashMap<String, String>());

        // put some values in the 3 HashMaps
        mPlatesList.get(0).put("Key1", "Value1");
        mPlatesList.get(0).put("Key2", "Value2");
        mPlatesList.get(1).put("Key3", "Value3");
        mPlatesList.get(2).put("Key4", "Value4");

        // build the table from mPlatesList
        Set<String> unionSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : mPlatesList) {
            unionSet.addAll(hashMap.values());
        }
        String[] table = unionSet.toArray(new String[unionSet.size()]);

        // print the table
        for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++)
            System.out.println(table[i]);

    }

}
```

Running the main method produces the following display:

```
Value3
Value4
Value1
Value2
```

EDIT 5: If you want to keep only values for which the key is `TAG_TARGA`, then replace the `// build the table from mPlateList` block by:

```
    // build the table from mPlatesList
    Set<String> unionSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : mPlatesList) {
        for(String key : hashMap.keySet())
            if(key.equals(TAG_TARGA))
                unionSet.add(hashMap.get(key));
    }
    String[] table = unionSet.toArray(new String[unionSet.size()]);
```

Comment: I want the values. How to convert values into string array?

Comment: any answer about what I wanted?

Comment: which libraries should include for this? because it shows red

Comment: THIS LINE   String [] table = unionSet.toArray(); Shows incopatible type required java.lang.String[] returned java.lang.Object[]

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Comment: (java.util.Set is required)

Comment: still java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Comment: I have done this:  Set<String> unionSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for(HashMap<String, String> hashMap : mPlatesList){
            unionSet.addAll(hashMap.values());
        }
        String [] table = unionSet.toArray(new String[unionSet.size()]);

        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.plates, R.id.title, table);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: What line throws the exception ?

This line:   String[] table = unionSet.toArray(new String[unionSet.size()]);

should be fine

Comment: Ok now is working but is showing even the hidden values. How to get only map.put(TAG_TARGA, targa); ? I mean a specific index values

Comment: it destroyed the other part of my project. Onclick listener doesn't display hidden values on the other page

Comment: See EDIT 5 to filter only values with the key TAG_TARGA

Comment: Yes but something is lost because it doesn't gets the other key values in the other page they are empty. When I click at a plate it leads to another page where i used to display color, type etc now they are empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58345/discussion-between-user3660185-and-zalgo).

Answer (score 0):

You can create some DTO instead of HashMap.