# setting text of a textview in an item of a listview from an edittext in the activity containing the listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, textview

i have an activtiy that represents an ingredients list creation and searching a recipe according to the list created,what i  want to do is get the text from the eduttext after the user inserts text and presses add,and then for the added text to appear in the list view,for some reason the text dosen't change and i have no idea why.  can anyone find my mistake?

[image: next to the x button there suppose to be text]

xml of a **single item** of the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientItemTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/removeButton"
         />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ingredientItemTv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ingredientItemTv"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/remove_icon"
        android:text="@string/remove" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

xml of the **activity**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fridgeReipeTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/fridgeReipeTitle" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ingredientEt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fridgeReipeTv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"   
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ingAddBtn"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ingredientEt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/aqua_button"
        android:text="@string/addString" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/recipeFindTv"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
             android:text="@string/findRecipe"
             android:textColor="@color/black" />
         <ListView
             android:id="@+id/lIngredientsListView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_above="@+id/recFindBtn"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/ingAddBtn"
             android:layout_marginBottom="79dp" >
         </ListView>
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/recFindBtn"
             android:layout_width="50dip"
             android:layout_height="50dip"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fridgeReipeTv"
             android:background="@drawable/find_icon"
             android:text="@string/find" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the java of the **activity**:

```
    package com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            public class FridgeRecipe extends Activity
            {
                ListView ingsListView; 
                EditText ingredientEt;
                TextView mainTitleTv,endTileTv;
                Button addingBtn, searchBtn,removeBtn;
                ArrayList<IngrdientView> ingredients;
                int idInList = 0;
                IngredientsListAdapter ila;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fridge_recipe);
                    ingsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lIngredientsListView);
                    ingredientEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ingredientEt);
                    mainTitleTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fridgeReipeTv);
                    endTileTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recipeFindTv);
                    addingBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ingAddBtn);
                    searchBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recFindBtn);
                    removeBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
                    ingredients = new ArrayList<IngrdientView>();
                    ila = new IngredientsListAdapter(FridgeRecipe.this, ingredients);
                    ingsListView.setAdapter(ila);
                    final String ingredient = ingredientEt.getText().toString();

                    addingBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            idInList++;
                            ingredients.add(new IngrdientView(ingredient,idInList));
                            ingredientEt.setText("");
                            ila.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });



                    ingsListView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);

                }
                // Create a message handling object as an anonymous class.
                private OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
                    {
                        if(v.getId() == R.id.removeButton)
                        {
                            ingredients.remove(position);


                        }
                    }
                };
            }
```

the java of the **adapter**:

```
package com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IngredientsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IngrdientView> implements ListAdapter, View.OnClickListener
    {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<IngrdientView> ingredients;

        public IngredientsListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<IngrdientView> ingredients) 
        {
            super(context, 0);
            this.context = context;
            this.ingredients = ingredients;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ingredients.size();
        }

        @Override
        public IngrdientView getItem(int position) 
        {
            return ingredients.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View root;
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
            }
            else
            {
                root = convertView;
                TextView ingredientName = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.ingredientItemTv);
                Button removeBtn = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
                IngrdientView ingView = ingredients.get(position);
                //ingredientName.setText(ingredientName.getText().toString());
                ingView.setIngredientName(ingredients.get(position).toString());
                removeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
            return root;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ingredients.size() == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954285/edittext-value-not-save-in-listview-dynamically/24956887#24956887

Answer (score 2):

One thing I can see which is wrong in your code is that you don't do anything to newly created views. Change your code to this and see if it changes anything:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View root;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
       }
        else
        {
            root = convertView;
        }

            TextView ingredientName = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.ingredientItemTv);
            Button removeBtn = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
            IngrdientView ingView = ingredients.get(position);
            //ingredientName.setText(ingredientName.getText().toString());
            ingView.setIngredientName(ingredients.get(position).toString());
            removeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        return root;
    }
```

You're not doing anything with your newly created view; you will need to populate it. On another note, you shouldn't re-subscribe the listener on cached views (i.e. after your else). You need to do it the first and only time you create your view (so in the `if(convertView == null)` otherwise you'll end up getting multiple call backs (at least in other programming languages you'd do).

I would also suggest using what android calls a "holder pattern" (Google it) for your list views to allow smooth scrolling and again, be careful with subscriptions.

I would also suggest making sure your getView() is called when you add a new item. From the brief overview of your code, it does seem to be the case but just to make sure, put in a break point and make sure it's called.

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html) developer guide for more examples and further reading.

*Also it's you've and not youv'e :)*

Comment: first of all,thanks for your answear!.that didn't chang a thing..plus,changing the convertView makes the app collapse..

Comment: What do you mean it makes the app collapse? Why would it do that? Are you having two different layouts for your listview items? Where do you get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Add the text into your Collection list (Arraylist or array). Modify the collection in the list view adapter (listview_adapter.setCollection (Your collection)). Then call  listview_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Or

Reinitialize the listview_adapter with new Collection list. and add the adapter into the listview.

Answer (score 0):

the changes that i made for it to work were in the adapter :

first change:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View root;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
    }
    else
    {
        root = convertView;
        TextView ingredientName = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.ingredientItemTv);       
        ingredientName.setText(ingredients.get(position).getIngredientName()+"");
        Button removeBtn = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
        removeBtn.setTag(position);
        //IngrdientView ingView = ingredients.get(position);
        removeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    return root;
}
```

second change:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        int index = (Integer)v.getTag();
        IngrdientView data = ingredients.get(index);
        ingredients.remove(data);
//      ((AdapterView)adapterView).setAdapter(null);
//      ((AdapterView)adapterView).setAdapter(this);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

hope this helps someone sometime..