# how to get text from edittext to listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to get the text from edittext to the listview. i have already added an image and textview in listview. now i need to know how to get the data from edittext and apply in listview. I'm adding my codes below :

activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    int[] image={R.drawable.confidential};

     String[] web = new String[] {"1","2"};
     Integer[] imageId = {
              R.drawable.confidential,R.drawable.confidential1};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText ed =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



        //final Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/d.ttf");
        // String ts1 = ed.getText().toString();


        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // String ts1 = ed.getText().toString();
                // tx.setText(ts1);
               //  tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
                 CustomList adapter = new
                            CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
                 ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                 list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });


    }}
```

my adapter class:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {

    super(context, R.layout.list, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
    }
    }
```

please help me with sample codes..!!  thank you!

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954285/edittext-value-not-save-in-listview-dynamically/24956887#24956887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spinner instead of using listview if you want single selection. Below code for listview item selected.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) 
{
        String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
        // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
   }
  }
 );
```

Comment: et.getText().toString(); it will return text contained with your edittext.